# Node.JS - fs.exists not working?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, if-statement

I'm a beginner in Node.js, and was having trouble with this piece of code.

```
var fs = require('fs');

Framework.Router = function() {

    this.run = function(req, res) {
        fs.exists(global.info.controller_file, function(exists) {
            if (exists) {
                            // Here's the problem
                            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
                var cname = App.ucfirst(global.info.controller)+'Controller';
                var c = require(global.info.controller_file);
                var c = new App[cname]();
                var action = global.info.action;
                c[action].apply(global.info.action, global.info.params);
                            res.end();
            } else {
                App.notFound();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
};
```

The problem lies in the part after checking if the 'global.info.controller_file' exists, I can't seem to get the code to work properly inside the: if (exists) { ... **NOT WORKING** }
I tried logging out the values for all the variables in that section, and they have their expected values, however the line: `c[action].apply(global.info.action, global.info.params);`
 is not running as expected. It is supposed to call a function in the controller_file and is supposed to do a simple `res.write('hello world');`. I wasn't having this problem before I started checking for the file using `fs.exists`. **Everything inside the if statement, worked perfectly fine before this check.**

Why is the code not running as expected? Why does the request just time out?
Does it have something to do with the whole synchronous vs asynchronous thing? (Sorry, I'm a complete beginner)

Thank you

Comment: RED FLAG! require is blocking IO, do not use it from within request handlers, it's also generally not good to use it dynamically. Load your modules during boot time, not run time

Comment: Why do you assign `var c` twice?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Oh... no reason for that lol, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: @generalhenry Aw man, so I should go about a completely different way of doing this? Because how can I use the 'require' function without knowing if the file I'm trying to require exists or not in the first place?

Comment: @user1302430 Can you give an example of the path in `global.info.controller_file` and describe the structure of your files? Also, how are you executing node? `node app.js`, or from a subdirectory?

Comment: @loganfsmyth At the root of the app, there is a file, 'app.js'. There are also 2 folders, 'app' & 'libs'. The 'libs' folder contains a file called 'Router.js', and that is where this piece of code is from. In the 'app' directory, there is another directory called 'controllers'. global.info.controller_file looks something like this: /home/username/framework/app/controllers/index_controller.js And yes I'm just running 'node app.js'

Comment: So if you `console.log(exists)` it prints `false`? If you do `ls ...` with the exact filename in the variable, it properly lists the file?

Comment: @loganfsmyth No, console.log(exists) prints `true`. And it is correct, the file does exist. The problem is the code inside the if statement. Everything inside the if statement works (I think), except for the last line (which did work before I started checking if the file existed).

Comment: Where/how are you passing `res` to `c[action].apply(...)`?

Comment: @robertklep The `res` is being passed to it through the `App` function. All the code is running, it's just that the request is timing out every time I try to see it in the browser.

Comment: Requests timing out usually means that there's no response being sent. Could it be that you're trying to reuse an old response object? Since I don't see you using the *current* `res` object anywhere.

Comment: If this was working prior to adding the `exists` check then you might have a scope problem with `this`. Once you're in a callback your `this` reference has changed. Try changing `c[action].apply(global.info.action, global.info.params);` to `c[action](global.info.params);`

The other thing you may want to try is pausing/resuming the request like so...

    `req.pause();
    fs.exists(global.info.controller_file, function(exists) {
    req.resume();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like others have commented, I would suggest you rewrite your code to bring it more in-line with the Node.js design patterns, then see if your problem still exists. In the meantime, here's something which may help:

The advice about not using `require` dynamically at "run time" should be heeded, and calling `fs.exists()` on every request is tremendously wasteful. However, say you want to load all *.js files in a directory (perhaps a "controllers" directory). This is best accomplished using an index.js file.

For example, save the following as `app/controllers/index.js`

```
var fs = require('fs');
var files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname);
var dotJs = /\.js$/;
for (var i in files) {
    if (files[i] !== 'index.js' && dotJs.test(files[i]))
        exports[files[i].replace(dotJs, '')] = require('./' + files[i]);
}
```

Then, at the start of `app/router.js`, add:

```
var controllers = require('./controllers');
```

Now you can access the `app/controllers/test.js` module by using `controllers.test`. So, instead of:

```
fs.exists(controllerFile, function (exists) {
    if (exists) {
        ...
    }
});
```

simply:

```
if (controllers[controllerName]) {
    ...
}
```

This way you can retain the dynamic functionality you desire without unnecessary disk IO.